# rails migration making a table with foreign keys while not re-indexing

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration

I am making a simple junction / relational table in my mysql database on my rails app.

I run:

```
bin/rails generate model personplace person:references place:references
```

I get a very large error that begins with:

```
Index name 'index_place_on_place_id' on table 'places' already exists/home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:939:in `add_index_options'
```

It is saying that I am indexing twice and that's not allowed.
I am not trying to index twice, I am just trying to make a couple foreign keys.

My goal is to make a good model/migration of a junction table with 2 foreign keys pointing to 2 separate tables.

EDIT 1:

The table places was made like this:

```
bin/rails generate model places person:references name:string creator:string size:integer
```

It already references the person table. That person the person that owns the place
The new table is for keeping track of all the people at the place.

EDIT 2:

```
class CreatePlaces < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :places do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :name
      t.string :creator
      t.integer :size

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you attach the migration that creates the places?

Comment: @MohamedOsama I have done so

Comment: @Rorschach - No, you haven't. :) You can find the migration in `db/migrations` folder, what you posted is just a generator that generates the migration file.

Comment: sorry, I added the command line to make the  migration to make places. In edit 2 I have added the migration file. @MohamedOsama